# html email table cell stacking

Tags: html, css, mobile

I have a request to do some complex stacking for an html email.  The HTML table looks like this:

```
<table>
<tr> <td>data...</td>  <td>data...</td>  <td>data...</td> </tr>
</table>
```

This shows as:

```
-------------------------
|data...|data...|data...|
-------------------------
```

On the mobile view I would like it to display as:

```
-----------------
|data...        |
-----------------
|data...|data...|
-----------------
```

What do I need to put into my media style sheet to make this happen?  Thanks!

Comment: Use [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) with its [Grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables are notoriously bad at responsiveness. Your best bet would be to add a media query that turns your table components (`table`, `tr` and `td`) into **[block-level elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements)** at a mobile width. As block-level elements they'll sit on top of each other by default.

From here, if you want to display two elements on the first line and one on the second, you can simply **[`float`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)** the cells to the `left`, and specify a **[`width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width)** on the `table` that will force the third cell to overflow onto the next line.

This can be seen in the following:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  table, tr, td {
    display: block;
  }
  
  table {
    width: 100px;
  }
  
  td {
    float: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>data...</td>
    <td>data...</td>
    <td>data...</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

To display one cell in the first row and two in the second, you can additionally specify that the first cell should take up the full 'row' width width **[`td:first-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type)**:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  table, tr, td {
    display: block;
  }
  
  table {
    width: 100px;
  }
  
  td {
    float: left;
  }
  
  td:first-of-type {
    width: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>data...</td>
    <td>data...</td>
    <td>data...</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That does exactly what you said, but I need to display one table cell on the first line and two on the second.

Comment: @ITGirl -- I misread that at first, my apologies. I've updated my answer to show a second snippet, showcasing one cell in the first row and two cells in the second row :)

Comment: I got it.  Thank you!  You're answer helped me figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Media Query](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) for responsive purpose in CSS3. Otherwise, if you want to make it simple, you could use Bootstrap v4.0 magic on [responsive table class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/#responsive-tables). It will be better to understand the concept of Media Query first.